# Cant properly pivot a dataframe coming from a .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

My goal is to reorder a dataframe for my convenience. When I set the dataframe "manually" I can do it without problems. But when I try after reading a `.csv` file, it fails. I will explain better with the examples:

**"Manual" Dataframe:**

- I import `pandas`
- Then I declare the dataframe I will be working with.
- I reorder the table as I wish it to be.
- Finally I see the results.

And here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Mes': ['Enero', 'Enero', 'Enero', 'Febrero', 'Febrero', 'Febrero'],
                   'Anio': ['2019', '2020', '2021', '2019', '2020', '2021'],
                   'Ventas': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],})
print(df)

df_ventas = df.pivot(index='Mes', columns='Anio', values='Ventas')
print(df_ventas)
```

The result is exactly what I want, I table that went from this:

```
       Mes   Anio  Ventas
0    Enero  2019       2
1    Enero  2020       3
2    Enero  2021       4
3  Febrero  2019       5
4  Febrero  2020       6
5  Febrero  2021       7
```

To this:

```
Anio      2019  2020  2021
Mes
Enero       2     3     4
Febrero     5     6     7
```

**`.csv` file:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("archivo.csv")

df_ventas = data.pivot(index = "Mes" , columns = "Anio", values = "Ventas")
print(df_ventas)
```

The `.csv` file has the same info, but the result is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "D:\Usuarios\wrodriguez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
        return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)   
    File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   
    File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in
        pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   
    File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in
        pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   
    File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in
        pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: 'Anio'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "D:\Usuarios\wrodriguez\Downloads\Codigos_Prueba_Python_RobotFramework\02_Vulgara\06_Graficas\01.py", line 10, in <module>
        df_ventas = data.pivot(index = "Mes" , columns = "Anio", values = "Ventas")   
    File "D:\Usuarios\wrodriguez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7793, in pivot
        return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)   
    File "D:\Usuarios\wrodriguez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 505, in pivot
        data_columns = [data[col] for col in columns_listlike]
    File "D:\Usuarios\wrodriguez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 505, in <listcomp>
        data_columns = [data[col] for col in columns_listlike]    
    File "D:\Usuarios\wrodriguez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
        indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)    
    File "D:\Usuarios\wrodriguez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
        raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'Anio'
```

I have been researching but I can't find anything that helps to understand why it cant be read as I did manually.

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your CSV file?

Comment: Mes,Anio,Ventas
Enero,2019,2
Enero,2020,3
Enero,2021,4
Febrero,2019,5
Febrero,2020,6
Febrero,2021,7

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Anio` instead of `Año`. Correct that:

```
df_ventas = data.pivot(index = "Mes" , columns = "Año", values = "Ventas")
```

Comment: I have it like that on the .csv. I will post both like Anio so there will not be missuderstading